# What is the basic structure of Indian Law?

Tags: india, civil-legal-system, indian-penal-code, indian-constitutional-law

Recently, I read the constitution of India and it was great. However, I'm unable to understand how Acts are made, what current classifications are. I find quite some overlap in laws, patchwork, inconsistencies, etc.

I'm a newbie so please feel free to go ahead with explaining basics too.

Comment: This may be of some use: [How are Indian laws classified and how many types of law are there?](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/82577/35069)

Comment: Ideally, you would do some of your own very basic research before asking a question. You might start on this first page of good search result: https://uk.practicallaw.thomsonreuters.com/w-017-5278?transitionType=Default&contextData=(sc.Default)